# SQL command to backup and restore a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, backup

Need to provide this facility on a button-click in my web application. Could be done using mysqldump, but for that I'd have to start an external process? (the command prompt)

Is there a simple SQL query that lets us backup and restore databases? (particularly for MySQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use MySQL 6, you're fine -- see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/backup-database-restore.html .  If you're on MySQL 5, things aren't so rosy -- you're probably better off with the mysqldump / external process approach.

Comment: The first link is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump is probably your best bet. You can save table rows with [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id3854478) and reload it with [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) but you have to do it table by table, and write out the table schemas to another file for a complete backup.

What's so bad about spawning a process to run mysqldump?

Answer (score 0):

You can either call the external command line executables [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/SQL/mysql_backup_restore.php) is a nice intro to that.

Or you run a couple of queries (like PHPMyAdmin does) and store the result somewhere by your own.

But there is no simple "one command" query for that.

Comment: what would be the "couple of queries" be?